# Regular inclusions: $\{b\in B:E(b^*b)=0\}$ is a two-sided ideal

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

From [Donsing-Pitts-2008, theorem 4.8]:

> For $A\subseteq B$ a regular inclusion, with $A$ abelian, and $E:B\to A$ its unique conditional expectation it holds:
> The left ideal
> $$L(E):=\{b\in B:E(b^*b)=0\}$$
> is a two-sided ideal $L(E)\trianglelefteq B$.

Can someone clarify the last point for the proof given there (see below) for the above statement?

*Sketch of proof from [Donsing-Pitts-2008]:*

Let $N(A\subseteq B)$ denote the normalizers.
Evidently it is sufficient to verify this for normalisers, i.e. for $n\in N(A\subseteq B)$ and $b\in B$,

$$E(b^*b)=0\implies E(n^*b^*bn)=0$$

As usual, $n\in N(A\subseteq B)$ induces a partial homeo on characters given by
$$n:\Gamma(A)\to\Gamma(A):\quad n(\alpha)a:=\frac{\alpha(n^*an)}{\alpha(n^*n)}$$
whenever $\alpha\in\Gamma(A)$ satisfies $\alpha(n^*n)\neq0$, which is the domain of the partial homeo.
By the unique extensions property, the induced character extends uniquely to the state
$$\beta:=n(\alpha)\circ E\in SB.$$
This is mentioned in the second paragraph of "4.1 CONTEXT FOR SECTION 4" on page 373.
Now since $E(b^*b)=0$ also indeed
$$\beta(b^*b)=\alpha(n^*E(b^*b)n)=0$$
and from here it is claimed that and hence $\alpha(E(n^*b^*bn))=0$ in this case as well.

Why is that so, can someone elaborate on this last point?
Am I maybe overlooking something?

[Donsing-Pitts-2008]: see https://www.jstor.org/stable/24715826